# Issue with ScrollView resetting it's position after calling [self.view addSubview:self.overlayView];

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollable input form that includes and emoticon picker that appears as an overlay with the frame set to the parent view:

```
self.emoticonOverlayView = [[EmoticonOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.emoticonOverlayView];
```

The emoticon overlay view pops up just fine, but the UIScrollView beneath it scrolls to the top. Any advice on why it is scrolling back to the top would be very helpful.

I tried to use this recommendation, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.
[UIScrollView unwanted scrolling after addSubview or changing frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176314/uiscrollview-unwanted-scrolling-after-addsubview-or-changing-frame)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try first adding content view to the scroll view and contain all your subviews inside this content view.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. You are correct that all my scrollview controls are not contained inside a single view that resides in my scrollview (which I've been seeing is best practice). Will try tomorrow when I get into work. Thx!

Comment: That totally fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: I posted it as the answer. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try first adding content view to the scroll view and contain all your subviews inside this content view.